# Internal Storage Video Downloder

Tags: video, storage, internals

```
  import android.os.Bundle; import android.util.Log; import android.view.LayoutInflater; import android.view.View; import android.view.ViewGroup; import android.widget.ProgressBar;  import androidx.annotation.NonNull; import androidx.annotation.Nullable; import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment; import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager; import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView; import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;  import com.example.movieflix.R; import com.example.movieflix.ui.adapters.DownloadAdapter; import com.example.movieflix.ui.adapters.FileUtils;  import java.io.File; import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.List;  public class DownloadFragment extends Fragment implements FileUtils.DownloadCallback {      private RecyclerView recyclerView;     private DownloadAdapter adapter;     private List<String> downloadedVideos;     private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;      @Nullable     @Override     public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_download, container, false);         recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_download);         recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));          swipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh_download);          // Initialize the list of downloaded videos         downloadedVideos = new ArrayList<>();          // Initialize and set the adapter to the RecyclerView         adapter = new DownloadAdapter(downloadedVideos);         recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);         swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this::refreshData);          return view;     }      // Method to handle swipe-to-refresh action     private void refreshData() {         // Clear the existing list of downloaded videos         downloadedVideos.clear();         // Populate downloaded videos list again         populateDownloadedVideos();         // Notify the adapter of data change         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();         // Stop the swipe-to-refresh animation         swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);     }      // Method to download a video using FileUtils and save it to internal storage     private void downloadVideo(String videoUrl, String name) {         FileUtils.saveVideoToInternalStorage(requireContext(), videoUrl, name, success -> {             if (success) {                 // If download is successful, add the video path to downloadedVideos list                 String filePath = requireContext().getFilesDir() + File.separator + name;                 downloadedVideos.add(filePath);                 Log.d("DownloadFragment", "File path added: " + filePath);                 // Notify the adapter of the data change                 adapter.notifyItemInserted(downloadedVideos.size() - 1);             } else {                 // Handle download failure                 Log.e("DownloadFragment", "Download failed for: " + name);             }         });     }      @Override     public void onDownloadComplete(boolean success) {         if (success) {             // Refresh the list of downloaded videos             populateDownloadedVideos();             // Notify the adapter of data change             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();         } else {             // Handle download failure             Log.e("DownloadFragment", "Download failed");         }     }       // Method to populate the list of downloaded videos     private void populateDownloadedVideos() {         try {             // Clear the existing list of downloaded videos             downloadedVideos.clear();              // Get the directory for downloaded videos             File directory = requireContext().getFilesDir();             if (directory != null && directory.isDirectory()) {                 // List all files in the directory                 File[] files = directory.listFiles();                 if (files != null) {                     for (File file : files) {                         // Add absolute path of each file to the downloadedVideos list                         if (file.isFile()) {                             downloadedVideos.add(file.getAbsolutePath());                         }                     }                 }             }         } catch (Exception e) {             e.printStackTrace();             Log.e("DownloadFragment", "Error populating downloaded videos: " + e.getMessage());         }     }  }
```

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.movieflix.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class DownloadAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DownloadAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<String> downloadedVideos;

    public DownloadAdapter(List<String> downloadedVideos) {
        this.downloadedVideos = downloadedVideos;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_download, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String videoPath = downloadedVideos.get(position);
        holder.bind(videoPath);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return downloadedVideos.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final TextView textViewTitle;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        }

        public void bind(String videoPath) {
            // Display video title or metadata in the item view
            textViewTitle.setText(getVideoTitleFromPath(videoPath));
        }

        private String getVideoTitleFromPath(String videoPath) {
            if (videoPath == null || videoPath.isEmpty()) {
                return "Unknown Title";
            }
            File file = new File(videoPath);
            return file.getName();
        }
    }
}
```

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class FileUtils {

    public interface DownloadCallback {
        void onDownloadComplete(boolean success);
    }

    public static void saveVideoToInternalStorage(Context context, String videoUrl, String name, DownloadCallback callback) {
        new DownloadTask(context, videoUrl, name, callback).execute();
    }

    private static class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        private final Context context;
        private final String videoUrl;
        private final String name;
        private final DownloadCallback callback;

        DownloadTask(Context context, String videoUrl, String name, DownloadCallback callback) {
            this.context = context;
            this.videoUrl = videoUrl;
            this.name = name;
            this.callback = callback;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(videoUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                // Create a new File object for saving the video in internal storage
                File directory = context.getFilesDir(); // Use internal storage directory
                File file = new File(directory, name);

                // Create buffered streams
                InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }

                // Close streams
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();

                return true; // Video saved successfully
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false; // Error occurred while saving video
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
            super.onPostExecute(success);
            callback.onDownloadComplete(success);
        }
    }
}
```

Hi, I am trying to download a video from url and save it in the internal app storage which can be viewed in the Downloaded Fragment. The problem is that when i click the download button video starts downloading and in notification bar downloading status also shows. But after download complete video is not appearing in the Downloaded Fragment. When i open the Downloaded Fragment there is a file name profileinstalled. this file remains there either i download or not. please help me with that